# Insert page number with adding some number of pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to insert into a document's footer a page number in this form:

```
{ ={ PAGE } + n}
```

where n is getting from the UserForm's text field. I've tried this:

```
dim r as Range
set r = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields(1).Code
doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields(1).Delete
n = UserForm1.TXT.text
r.Fields.Add Range:=r, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:=" ={ PAGE } + " + n
doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Update
```

This macro inserts the text properly, but it gives a syntax error in the footer (it doesn't like the "{" bracket). How can I insert this field?

Comment: Is there a reason for using a formula field instead of setting the document's starting page #? FWIW, calculated page #s will not display the calculated value in cross-references or in a Table of Contents, only the underlying page #.

Comment: @macropod Pages are shown in the footer, as it's presented here, and in the header in a format "Page # of SectionPages". So if the starting page is set implicitly, it causes the header page numbers to be shown incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your code deletes the first field in the primary footer. Assuming, therefore, there is always a field there coded as per your { ={ PAGE } + n}, all you need is:

```
Sub UpdatePageField()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  .ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
  With .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Find.Execute FindText:="=^19 PAGE ^21 + " '{ ={ PAGE } + n}
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .MoveEnd wdWord, 1
      .Text = UserForm1.TXT.Text
    End If
  End With
  .ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you use a Custom Document Property and code the field in the footer like:

```
{={PAGE}+{DOCPROPERTY Offset}}
```

all the code you'd need is:

```
Sub UpdatePageNum()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  .CustomDocumentProperties("Offset").Value = UserForm1.TXT.Text
  .PrintPreview
  .ClosePrintPreview
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I also had to add `Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)`.

Comment: With the second macro, that wouldn't be necessary.